# How to solve this system of 1D-ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How does one solve this system of 1D-ODE.

$$\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t} = \omega x+g\nu^*\exp(\text{i}2\omega t)x^* \\
\frac{\text{d}x^*}{\text{d}t} = -\text{i}\omega x^*-\text{i}g\nu \exp(-\text{i}2\omega t)x,$$ with the initial condition that $x(0) = 0 = x^*(0)$.

What I've done. Taking another derivative of the first equation gives us,

$$\ddot x + \omega \dot x+\text{i}(gb)^2x = -3\text{i}\omega g b x^*,$$ where $b = \nu \exp(-\text{i}2 \omega t)$. $b$ clearly is a function of time, $t$. How to proceed?

Comment: Separating the real and imaginary parts of the complex-valued function $x(t)$, you obtain a homogeneous matrix differential equation of the form $\boldsymbol{\dot{x}} = \boldsymbol{\underline{A}}(t) \boldsymbol{x}$ for the unknown (real-)vector-valued function $\boldsymbol{x} = (\mathrm{Re}(x),\mathrm{Im}(x))^{\top} \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Yes that's right. Have tried that. So I use the usual approach of taking $\exp(\text{i}\lambda t)$ as the trial solution with, $\lambda$ being the eigenvalue of the $\mathbf{A}$ matrix?

Comment: Because $\boldsymbol{A}$ is variable, the matrix exponential becomes a bit more complicated. But actually, it seems enough to look at the initial conditions: $x \equiv 0$ is a solution of the initial-value problem.